# Как поменять background view в темах?

Tags: android, android-style, android-themes

Что нужно вписать в темы, чтобы они устанавливали background?

Я попробовал:

```
 <style name="ConstraintBackground" >
     <item name="background">@drawable/Mydrawable</item>
 </style>
```

Написал в нужном мне view:

```
android:theme="@style/ConstraintBackground"
```

Но background не меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ошиблись с названием атрибута, правильно будет `android:background`, а не просто `background`, например:

```xml
<item name="android:background">#ebaeba</item>
```

Посмотрите больше примеров того, как задавать стили, в [официальном гайде](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes).